# Speed issue while trying to read/write BLE characteristic second time

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have an external BLE device, in which I can read/write the data up to 500-800 bytes.

I'm writing by chunks sized to 200 bytes, and the reading is limited on the BLE device side by 20 bytes per packet.

After I connected and do some operation (read / writeWithResponse) - it takes approx. 1 sec, but every operation after that takes up to 1 min, e.g. while I'm reading, transferring every packet takes about 2 seconds.

If I disconnect and connect to the device, only the first operation is fast.

The code is pretty simple - I just splitting data (in case of writing) and sending it by chunks. Every next chunk is sending just after I receive callback `didWriteValueForCharacteristic:`.

How can I improve the speed? Do you have suggestions: why only the first operation with BLE module is fast?

Comment: You should increase the MTU. You could also use Write Without Response to avoid all the round trips a Long Write otherwise takes.

Comment: @Emil Hi, thx for your help -- how can I increase MTU? On the BLE device side only?

Comment: Yes. iOS already negotiates a big MTU, so make sure the peripheral does too.

Comment: Could you show some code for this? You mention that every operation takes up to 1 min, but every packet takes 2 seconds - I don't understand what this means. Do you have the connection parameters (latency, interval) from your peripheral? iOS should connect at 15ms-30ms (if the peripheral is set to a very low connection interval) - which means regardless of MTU, you shouldn't see this behaviour.

Comment: @SJoshi Hi, I'll try to update the question with code tomorrow. Regarding time - sorry for my en, I just want to say -- that the duration of whole operation (200 bytes / 10 packets 20 bytes each) is about 30 seconds, because sending each packet takes about 2-3 seconds. Anyway we switched to the writing without response and the situation here is much better 

Comment: @ShurupuS Good to hear. Yeah, there is nothing inherent about CoreBluetooth that would cause that problem. My one guess is that your peripheral has strange connection interval or latency settings, or alternatively you're trying to repeatedly send stuff before your write with response completes. Write with response basically means you might take 2 connection intervals to send a single 20 byte packet (and wait for the response)